# The window doesn't appear when I run my pyqt code

Tags: python, pyqt

The installed pyqy version is pyqt5 and I want to window appreas on screen, but it doesn't

codes :

```
    import sys
    from PyQt5 import QtGui
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow


    class Window(QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()

            self.title = "Hello Guy!!!"
            self.top = 100
            self.left = 100
            self.width = 680
            self.height = 500
            self.init()

        def init(self):
            self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
            self.setGeometry(self.top, self.left, self.width, self.height)


    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

And When I run the application nothing will apear on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you forgot to call `.show()` method of QMainWindow Class

**Original Code**

```
App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

**Bug Fix**

```
App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
window.show()     # this will load the window 
sys.exit(App.exec())
```